# OpenLayers 3 applying dynamic style with resolution function

Tags: openlayers-3

I am adding a dynamic style to vector features on my map like this...

```
 var source = webLayer.getSource();
                                                var features = source.getFeatures();


                                                var templateStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: convertHex(Layer.LayerStyle.FillColor, '0.5') }),
                                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: convertHex(Layer.LayerStyle.LineColor, '0.5') }),
                                                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                                                        font: '24px Verdana',
                                                        text: webLayer.U.label,
                                                        offsetY: 20,
                                                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                                            color: [255, 255, 255, 0.8]
                                                        })
                                                    })
                                                });


                                                var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
                                                    style: templateStyle
                                                });

                                                map.addInteraction(select);                                                    webLayer.setVisible(Visibility);
                                                features[0].setStyle(templateStyle);
```

I would also like to include a resolution function for the text so it only shows at a certain resolution such as...

```
style: function (feature, resolution) {
                            var text = resolution * 100000 < 10 ? response.FieldList[key].SomeText: '';

                            if (text != "") {
                                styleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                        color: '#319FD3',
                                        width: 1
                                    }),
                                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                                        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                                        text: text,
                                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                            color: '#000'
                                        }),
                                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                            color: '#fff',
                                            width: 3
                                        })
                                    }),
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: convertHex(response.FieldList[key].Shade, '0.5')
                                    })
                                })];
                            }
```

but have not been able to figure out how to implement this with creating the style like this...

```
var templateStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: convertHex(Layer.LayerStyle.FillColor, '0.5') }),
                                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: convertHex(Layer.LayerStyle.LineColor, '0.5') }),
                                                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                                                        font: '24px Verdana',
                                                        text: webLayer.U.label,
                                                        offsetY: 20,
                                                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                                            color: [255, 255, 255, 0.8]
                                                        })
                                                    })
                                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up realizing that I can do the same type of styling function I used to create the vector features with initially...I did have to inject the controller used to create the map and go after the attributes that way.

```
var source = webLayer.getSource();
                                                var features = source.getFeatures();

                                                var styleCache = {};
                                                var feature = features[0];
                                                var view = map.getView();
                                                var shade = webLayer.U.shade;
                                                if (shade == "")
                                                {
                                                    shade = Layer.LayerStyle.FillColor;
                                                }
                                                var templateStyle = function (feature, resolution) {
                                                    var text = view.getResolution() * 100000 < 10 ? webLayer.U.label : '';

                                                    if (text != "") {
                                                        styleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
                                                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                                                color: '#319FD3',
                                                                width: 1
                                                            }),
                                                            text: new ol.style.Text({
                                                                font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                                                                text: text,
                                                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                                                    color: '#000'
                                                                }),
                                                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                                                    color: '#fff',
                                                                    width: 3
                                                                })
                                                            }),
                                                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                                                color: rcisWebMapUtilities.convertHex(shade, '0.5')
                                                            })
                                                        })];
                                                    }
                                                    else if (text == "") {
                                                        styleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
                                                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                                                color: convertHex(shade, '0.5')
                                                            })
                                                        })
                                                        ]
                                                    } return styleCache[text];
                                                }


                                                var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
                                                    style: templateStyle
                                                });

                                                features[0].setStyle(templateStyle);
                                                webLayer.setVisible(Visibility);
```